# Invoke date within an awk command to format output

Tags: command-line, awk, date

I have a `csv` file in the following format:

```
20171129,1
20171201,0.5
20171201,0.5
20171202,1.25
20171202,1.75
```

I use the following command to sum up the second field if it is following the same date with this command:

```
awk -F ',' '{a[$1] += $2} END{for (i in a) print "On " i, "you spend: "a[i] " hour(s)"}' << "file.csv"
```

the output I get looks like this:

```
On 20171129 you spend: 1 hour(s)
On 20171201 you spend: 1 hour(s)
On 20171202 you spend: 3 hour(s)
```

what I want to achieve now is format the date as if I would with:

```
awk -F ',' '{a[$1]} END{for (i in a) print i}' << "file.csv" \
 | date +"%a, %d.%m.%Y" -f -

# prints:
Wed, 29.11.2017
Fri, 01.12.2017
Sat, 02.12.2017
```

so my final result would look like:

```
On Wed, 29.11.2017 you spend: 1 hour(s)
On Fri, 01.12.2017 you spend: 1 hour(s)
On Sat, 02.12.2017 you spend: 3 hour(s)
```

is it possible to invoke `date` within the `awk` command to format the output?

Comment: What's Mi? Minday?

Comment: @DavidConrad `Mi` is german for `Mittwoch` = `Wednesday`, thought this was not too much of a thing, but you are right, I should edit the snippet to: `Wed`, `Fri`, `Sat`, making more sense on an english QA board :-)

Comment: Oh, that's okay. I thought it might have been a typo for Mo (Monday) but wasn't sure. Sorry.

Comment: @DavidConrad All good! thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use **gawk** which has the **strftime** and **mktime** functions (https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html).

```
gawk -F ',' '{a[$1] += $2} END{for (i in a) print "On " strftime("%a, %d.%m.%Y", mktime( substr(i,1,4) " " substr(i,5,2) " " substr(i,7,2) " 0 0 0" )) " you spend: "a[i] " hour(s)" }' files.csv
```

In more details:

```
gawk -F ',' '
  {
    a[$1] += $2
  }
  END{
    for (i in a) {

      # mktime needs a date formated like this "2017 12 31 23 59 59"
      # strftime needs a Unix timestamp (produced by mktime)

      print "On " strftime("%a, %d.%m.%Y", mktime( substr(i,1,4) " " substr(i,5,2) " " substr(i,7,2) " 0 0 0" )) " you spend: "a[i] " hour(s)"

    }
  }' files.csv
```

With a basic **awk**, you need to call the command and read its result with **getline**:

```
awk -F ',' '{a[$1] += $2} END{ for (i in a) { COMMAND = "date +\"%a, %d.%m.%Y\" -d " i ; if ( ( COMMAND | getline DATE ) 0 ) { print "On " DATE " you spend: "a[i] " hour(s)" } ; close(COMMAND) } }' files.csv
```

In more details:

```
awk -F ',' '
  {
    a[$1] += $2
  }
  END{
    for (i in a) {

      # Define command to call

      COMMAND = "date +\"%a, %d.%m.%Y\" -d " i

      # Call command and check that it prints something
      # We put the 1st line of text displayed by the command in DATE

      if ( ( COMMAND | getline DATE ) > 0 ) {
        # Print the result
        print "On " DATE " you spend: "a[i] " hour(s)"
      }

      # Close the command (important!)
      # Your child process is still here if you do not close it

      close(COMMAND)
    }
  }' files.csv
```